# Windows batch: nested for loops with variable dependence

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, for-loop

I'm new to windows scripting (after using bash for many years). I have a problem understanding the way windows batch files execute for loops.

I have three nested for loops, with the variable of each inner loopd depending on the variable of the loop it resides within:

```
for %%i in (0,1,%maxnum%) do (

for %%j in (0,1,%%i) do (

for %%k in (0,1,%%j) do (

echo L%%i_M%%j_N%%k ) ) )
```

If I set "maxnum" equal to 2, this loop should print out:

```
L0_M0_N0
L1_M0_N0
L1_M1_N0
L1_M1_N1
L2_M0_N0
L2_M1_N0
L2_M1_N1
L2_M2_N0
L2_M2_N1
L2_M2_N2
```

and no more than these 10 strings. However, I notice that if for instance %%i=0, the second for loop loops over %%j in (0,1,0) and executes its contents, not only for %%j=0 but also for %%j=1, which is irritating!

I restricted the output by adding if statements before the echo:

```
for %%i in (0,1,%maxnum%) do (

for %%j in (0,1,%%i) do (

for %%k in (0,1,%%j) do (

if %%k LEQ %%j (

if %%j LEQ %%i (

echo L%%i_M%%j_N%%k ) ) ) ) )
```

This then prints out:

```
L0_M0_N0  
L0_M0_N0  
L0_M0_N0  
L0_M0_N0  
L1_M0_N0  
L1_M0_N0  
L1_M1_N0  
L1_M1_N1  
L1_M1_N1  
L1_M1_N0  
L1_M1_N1  
L1_M1_N1  
L2_M0_N0  
L2_M0_N0  
L2_M1_N0  
L2_M1_N1  
L2_M1_N1  
L2_M2_N0  
L2_M2_N1  
L2_M2_N2
```

and so for the strings LX_MY_NZ, it is true that Z<=Y<=X but some strings are repeated, which is problematic for what I want to use this code for.

Is there a way around this situation when the start and end values of the for loop are the same? Or am I just not understanding how to use for loops in windows batch files?

Your input is very much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `/L` parameter to the `for` statements.

```
FOR /L %variable IN (start,step,end) DO command [command-parameters]

    The set is a sequence of numbers from start to end, by step amount.
    So (1,1,5) would generate the sequence 1 2 3 4 5 and (5,-1,1) would
    generate the sequence (5 4 3 2 1)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! I can't believe I didn't see that! Without the /L command, it is simply cycling through the numbers (0,1,0) rather than starting at 0 and incrementing by 1 until it gets to 0...

Comment: I feel a bit silly about asking the question now! Thanks for your help :)